# Passing boost::bind parameters as arguments

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I have wrote somo code that works fine. But I would like to write it in another way and I don't know how to do.
This is what I have done :

```
class A {
public:
    void doAction();
}

typedef boost::signals2::signal<void(bool)> OnTriggered;
typedef OnTriggered::slot_type OnTriggeredSlot;

class B {
public:
    void add(const OnTriggeredSlot &iSlot);
}

void A::doAction() {
    B b;
    b.add(boost::bind(&A::doAction, this, _1));
}
```

Here is what I would like to do :

```
void A::doAction() {
    B b;
    b.add(&A::doAction, this);
}
```

I don't know how to modify the "add" method of the "B" class.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution :

```
    class B
    {
    public:
        template<class SlotClass> boost::signals2::connection add(SlotClass * obj, void(SlotClass::*func)(bool))
            {
                return m_sig.connect(boost::bind(func, obj, _1));
            }
    }
```